# Pass fileurl parameter into shortcode from Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a custom shortcode that uses another shortcode for a couple audio players on a Grid displaying a custom post type using Visual Composer.

The audio player that I would like to use is the Compact Audio Player plugin which uses a shortcode of `[sc_embed_player fileurl="URL OF THE MP3 FILE"]`.

What I want to do is create 2 custom shortcodes that inject the correct mp3 url into the `fileurl=" "` path when the grid loads. I'm using advanced custom fields and the code that I am using for one shortcode in my `functions.php` now is (I plan on duplicating when I can get this one to work for the other shortcode):

```
function get_generic_demo() {
$demo = get_field( 'generic_demo');
echo do_shortcode('[sc_embed_player fileurl="'.$demo['url'].'"]');
}
add_shortcode( 'generic_demo', 'get_generic_demo');
```

However, it gives me an error saying I didn't input a valid url when the grid displays when my custom shortcode is entered.

I've tried both setting the return from ACF to file url and the array (as used above).

I've also tried:

```
$demo = get_field( 'generic_demo', $post->ID);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you able to return **ANY** data from the $demo variable?

Comment: not when using the variable. I am however able to get the correct data when coding in the template by using:
    <?php $generic_demo = get_field( 'generic_demo' ); ?>
      <?php if ( $generic_demo ) { ?>
      <audio controls src="<?php echo $generic_demo['url']; ?>"></audio>
      <?php } ?><br>

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `echo` in your shortcode. Use `return` instead.

```
function get_generic_demo() {
    //Get the field's value
    $demo = get_field( 'generic_demo');
    //Save the URL into a variable
    $url = $demo['url'];
    // Pass it to the other shortcode and return its value
    return do_shortcode('[sc_embed_player fileurl="'.$url.'"]');
}
add_shortcode( 'generic_demo', 'get_generic_demo');
```

Also make sure your fields contain the proper URL format. Dump the variable by using `var_dump` to verify it. This is most likely where your problem is coming from.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I dumped the variable by using
    var_dump($demo); 
which came back NULL as well as 
    var_dump($url); 

which also returned null. Really bizarre because it works fine on the single page where its hard coded into the template but i'm having a really difficult time passing this darn URL into the shortcode...

Comment: @Kyle If the `$demo` variable is `NULL`, then the problem is not the shortcode. You are probably retrieving the wrong field. You might wanna check that again.

Comment: I just double checked and the field_name is indeed generic_demo and the return value is set it File Array. I tried to add a second parameter of
    get_field( 'generic_demo',  $attachment->ID ) but everthing i've tried is returning NULL. I've also tried to change the return on ACF to File URL and still doesn't work. Super bizarre since the field works fine on the single page where it's hardcoded

Comment: @Kyle The question is where do you use this code? Does it have access to post ID?

Comment: I am using the custom [generic_demo] shortcode in a text field on the Grid Builder in Visual Composer. I want to be able to display an audio file in each post on the post grid that I'm building so the user can preview the audio file without going into the single post page for that post. Do I need to create a foreach loop inside that function so it pulls in each audio file when it renders the Featured Image, Excerpt, etc? Just thinking out loud...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% positive if this will fix it, but try pulling the global post variable into your shortcode declaration function:

```
function get_generic_demo() {
    global $post;
    //Get the field's value
    $demo = get_field('generic_demo');
    //Save the URL into a variable
    $url = $demo['url'];
    // Pass it to the other shortcode and return its value
    return do_shortcode('[sc_embed_player fileurl="'.$url.'"]');
}
add_shortcode( 'generic_demo', 'get_generic_demo');
```

---

** RESPONSE EDIT - 2017-06-20 @ 11:45AM **

The issue appears to be that however Visual Composer is building the grid, the CPT IDs aren't being acknowledged. How is the rest of the data being set for each item entry (i.e. the title and description of each item)? Are you manually entering it into the grid or is it being automatically generated?

Comment: unfortunately that didn't do anything. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I assume that the 'generic_demo' field is an ACF file field, correct?

Comment: yes sir! It's working fine when i pull it in on a single.php page and its returning the url correctly. Just not when i'm trying to pass it through the fileurl of the Compact Audio shortcode

Comment: So, the file is declared on a single post/cpt...are you using the shortcode on an alternative page/post or on that same page that you've attached the file to?

Comment: I'm using the shortcode '[generic_demo]' in a text field on the Grid Builder in Visual Composer that is displaying a Grid of my CPT Posts

Comment: So, are you in some way setting the CPT post id for each shortcode declaration? Is it set in a loop or something, where you are looping through all of your posts?

Comment: I don't think so. Not sure how I would go about doing that. I just assumed that passing the ACF url in to the fileurl parameter in the other shortcode and then using it in the Visual Composer Grid Builder, it would work. Would Visual Composer be handling the loop when its grabbing all of the posts for that CPT? Ive tried passing $post->ID as a second parameter inside of the get_field('generic_demo', $post->ID) thinking that would help but it doesnt. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that the ID for CPT post(s) aren't being declared in the grid items that Visual Composer is generating. Do you have a site URL that I could see first hand? I may be able to shed some light on how to work around Visual Composer's limitations.

Comment: Sure. [link](http://iheart.jinglebank.com/jingles) you'll notice the red error on each of the posts

Comment: its all being generated by Visual Composer based on the fields I chose using Grid Builder when building the Grid layout template.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure that you'll be able to do that within Visual Composer. You will probably have to manually code a layout.

Comment: All good, dude. Best of luck to you.